How to maintain User(jhi_user) and Authority(jhi_authority) entity based on Jhipster v8.7.3?
My project is based on jhipster microservice architecture. I want to add extra columns on entity User and Authority, and building relationship between both above entities and the custom entities, is it still the same way to main it manually refering to this question?
How to add field to User (jhi_user) entity Jhipster?
I trid to modify authority in jdl file, but no extra code could be generated without any errors.
enter image description here
I add following code in my jdl file.
entity Authority(jhi_authority) {
  /** name */
  name String
  /** code */
  code String
  /** info */
  info String
  /** order */
  order Integer
  /** display */
  display Boolean
}

relationship ManyToOne{
  Permission{authority(name)} to Authority with builtInEntity
}

Reproduction step:

executive jhipster jdl project.jdl --auto-crlf
waiting for the command executed successfully, then modify the jdl file just adding the code mentioned above into the project.jdl file.
executive jhipster jdl project.jdl --auto-crlf

